# grep pattern from file, print the pattern instead matched string

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I want to grep with patterns from file containing regex.
When the pattern matches, it prints the matched stringa but not the pattern.
How can I get the pattern instead matched strings?

pattern.txt

```
Apple (Ball|chocolate|fall) Donut
donut (apple|ball) Chocolate
Donut Gorilla Chocolate
Chocolate (English|Fall) apple gorilla
gorilla chocolate (apple|ball)
(ball|donut) apple
```

strings.txt

```
apple ball Donut
donut ball chocolate
donut Ball Chocolate
apple donut
chocolate ball Apple
```

This is grep command

```
grep -Eix -f pattern.txt strings.txt
```

This command prints matched strings from strings.txt

```
apple ball Donut
donut ball chocolate
donut Ball Chocolate
```

But I want to find which patterns were used to match from pattern.txt

```
Apple (Ball|chocolate|fall) Donut
donut (apple|ball) Chocolate
```

The pattern.txt can be lower cases, upper cases, line with regex and without, free numbers of words and regex elements. There is no other kind of regex than brackets and pipe.

I don't want to use loop to read pattern.txt each line to grep as it's slow.
Is there way to print which pattern or line number of pattern file in grep command? or any other command than grep can do the job not too slow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `grep` I have no idea but with GNU awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }      # for case insensitivity
NR==FNR {                     # process pattern file
    a[$0]                     # hash the entries to a
    next                      # process next line
}
{                             # process strings file
    for(i in a)               # loop all pattern file entries
        if($0 ~ "^" i "$") {  # if there is a match (see comments)
            print i           # output the matching pattern file entry
            # delete a[i]     # uncomment to delete matched patterns from a
            # next            # uncomment to end searching after first match
        }
}' pattern strings
```

outputs:

```
D (A|B) C
```

For each line in `strings` script will loop every `pattern` line to see if there are more than one match. There is only one match due to case-sensitivity. You can battle that, for example, using GNU awk's [`IGNORECASE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html).

Also, if you want each matched one pattern file entry to be outputed once, you could delete them from `a` after first match: add `delete a[i]` after the `print`. That might give you some performance advantage also.

Comment: This code works, but matching with partial strings too. if I change "$0 ~ i" to  "$0 == i" then it matches only entire string, but then problem to match with escaped characters... how can I write something like "=~ ^pattern$" in awk?

Comment: Thanks, now it does what I need, this is like double speed of if I called grep by loop!

Comment: You're welcome. I added the previous and `IGNORECASE` to the code.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed the Input_file(s) so adding solutions as per changed Input_file(s) too now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
   a[toupper($1),toupper($NF)]
   b[toupper($2)]
   next
}
{
   val=toupper($2)
   gsub(/\)|\(|\|/," ",val)
   num=split(val,array," ")
   for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
      if(array[i] in b){
        flag=1
        break
      }
   }
}
flag && ((toupper($1),toupper($NF)) in a){
  print;
  flag=""
}' string pattern
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Apple (Ball|chocolate|fall) Donut
donut (apple|ball) Chocolate
```

---

---

***Solution 1st:*** Adding a generic solution where let's say your Input_file named `pattern` have more than 2 values on 2nd field eg--> `(B|C|D|E)` then following may help you here.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
   a[$1,$NF]
   b[toupper($2)]
   next
}
{
   val=$2
   gsub(/\)|\(|\|/," ",val)
   num=split(val,array," ")
   for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
      if(array[i] in b){
        flag=1
        break
      }
   }
}
flag && (($1,$NF) in a)
{
  flag=""
}' string pattern
```

---

---

***Solution 2nd:*** Could you please try following. But strictly considering that your Input_file(s) are same pattern as per shown samples only(where I am considering that your Input_file named `pattern` will have only 2 values in 2nd field of it)

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1,$NF]
  b[toupper($2)]
  next
}
{
  val=$2
  gsub(/\)|\(|\|/," ",val)
  split(val,array," ")
}
((array[1] in b) || (array[2] in b)) && (($1,$NF) in a)
' string pattern
```

Output will be as follows.

```
A (B|C) D
D (A|B) C
```

Comment: This so high performance solution, but my example was bad, the actual file is more flexible, can be various word number, lower cases & upper cases, line without regex, actual bracket escaped and other symbols etc.

Comment: Any of answers isn't working yet with my actual files, which are more complex text as explained above, I am trying modify your code but I'm still not getting the right result. Please let me edit the example.

Comment: @haruka.k, please check my EDIT solution and let me know then? Previous one would have worked too, only thing problem was with small and capital letters. Check now, also try to up-vote people who are trying to help you and select an answer out of all as correct once you find it too, cheers

Comment: This code still doesn't work on mine and I'm having trouble to understand the details... when you split val by space to array, what happens if there is only one word in the line?

Comment: @haruka.k, please post example here what do you mean by 1 word please?

Comment: @haruka.k, I could see my code is working perfectly fine with your given example, please do let me know what is not working and I will try to fix it then.

Comment: I found now in my work pattern file there are regex without space like pattern "aaa(bbb|ccc)ddd" string "aaabbbddd". is space necessary in your code? Could you possibly comment bit in your code to help me to understand what they are doing?

Comment: @haruka.k, yes space is necessary in my code(as default field separator is space in `awk`) I am using that only. Will add explanation after dinner, do you have a file without spaces too?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with bash built-ins:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# case insensitive
shopt -s nocasematch

# associative array of patterns
declare -A patterns=()
while read -r p; do
    patterns["$p"]=1
done < pattern.txt

# read strings, test remaining patterns,
# if match print pattern and remove it from array    
while read -r s; do
    for p in "${!patterns[@]}"; do
        if [[ $s =~ ^$p$ ]]; then
            printf "%s\n" "$p"
            unset patterns["$p"]
        fi
    done
done < strings.txt
$ ./foo.sh
Apple (Ball|chocolate|fall) Donut
donut (apple|ball) Chocolate
```

Not sure about the performance but as there are no child processes, it should be much faster than invoking grep for each pattern.

Of course, if you have millions of patterns, storing them in an associative array could exhaust your available memory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe switch the paradigm?

```
while read pat
do grep -Eix "$pat" strings.txt >"$pat" &
done <patterns.txt
```

That's going to make ugly filenames, but you'd have clear lists per set. You could scrub the filenames first if you prefer. Maybe (assuming the patterns resolve to uniqueness this easily...)

```
while read pat
do grep -Eix "$pat" strings.txt >"${pat//[^A-Z]/}" &
done <patterns.txt
```

It ought to be reasonably quick, and is relatively simple to implement.
Hope that helps.