# How to change a pattern in a file that match in pattern from column 1 in other file, and then print the pattern of column 2?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, vlookup, gsub

I have a file `gff3.txt` with this kind of datas (billions of lines):

```
 scaffold1000|size145372 . gene 16987 23149 . - . ID=evm.TU.scaffold1000|size145372.2;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold1000|size145372.2
 scaffold1000|size145372 . mRNA 16987 23149 . - . ID=evm.model.scaffold1000|size145372.2;Parent=evm.TU.scaffold1000|size145372.2;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold1000|size145372.2
 scaffold1000|size145372 . exon 22965 23149 . - . ID=evm.model.scaffold1000|size145372.2.exon1;Parent=evm.model.scaffold1000|size145372.2
 scaffold9|size467357 . gene 373475 396789 . + . ID=evm.TU.scaffold9|size467357.56;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold9|size467357.56
 scaffold9|size467357 . mRNA 373475 396789 . + . ID=evm.model.scaffold9|size467357.56;Parent=evm.TU.scaffold9|size467357.56;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold9|size467357.56
 scaffold9|size467357 . exon 373475 373695 . + . ID=evm.model.scaffold9|size467357.56.exon1;Parent=evm.model.scaffold9|size467357.56
 ...
```

And an other file `position.txt (billions of lines):

```
 scaffold1000|size145372.2  scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149
 scaffold9|size467357.56    scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789
 ...
```

And I search to obtain this:

```
 scaffold1000|size145372 . gene 16987 23149 . - . ID=evm.TU.scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149
 scaffold1000|size145372 . mRNA 16987 23149 . - . ID=evm.model.scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149;Parent=evm.TU.scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149
 scaffold1000|size145372 . exon 22965 23149 . - . ID=evm.model.scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149.exon1;Parent=evm.model.scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149
 scaffold9|size467357 . gene 373475 396789 . + . ID=evm.TU.scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789
 scaffold9|size467357 . mRNA 373475 396789 . + . ID=evm.model.scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789;Parent=evm.TU.scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789
 scaffold9|size467357 . exon 373475 373695 . + . ID=evm.model.scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789.exon1;Parent=evm.model.scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789
 ...
```

So I would like to find in the column `$9` of the `gff3.txt` file the patterns that match with the column `$1` in `position.txt` and then change them with the pattern of the column 2 of the `position.txt` file.

I tried with awk:

```
 awk '
     NR==FNR{a[$9]
     next
 }
 ($2 in a) {
     print
 }' gff3.txt position.txt > output.txt
```

But this didn't work. Maybe is due to because of the patterns in the column `$9` of the `gff3.txt` are included in other information?

I also try to adapt these threads with my datas but I didn't achieve it: [stackoverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822216/grep-pattern-from-file-print-the-pattern-instead-matched-string), [stackoverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command), [stackoverflow3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546949/how-to-replace-a-pattern-in-one-file-with-the-contents-of-another-file-using-s), [stackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115262/find-pattern-from-one-file-listed-in-another)...

Any advice for coding this in `awk`, `sed` or others will be very appreciated.

Comment: what's the size of `position.txt` file (number of entries) ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Both files have billions of lines (I add this info with edit)

Comment: Don't ``awk` '` just `awk '`. Without backticks.. Can you say exactly what is the value of `$9`? From these columns from `gff3.txt`? You want to `join` files, but I can't see on which field do you join them. You want to just substitute `scaffold1000|size145372.2` for `scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149` ? Are the files sorted on a specifing column? Can they be joined on the first column before the dot?

Comment: @ Kamil Cuk Thanks, it was just an error when I wrote my question, I was just awk when I try it. I edit my post, thanks again.

Comment: Will just a simple `sed 's/scaffold9|size467357.56/scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789/g'` do?

Comment: @KamilCuk the both file are sorted. I have billions of scaffoldXXX|sizeXXXX.XX that I want to change into scaffoldXXX|sizeXXXX:XXX-XXX

Comment: Sorted using which field? Sorted alphabetically? If they are properly sorted ( I see that `join -11 -21 <(<position.txt sed 's/^\([^\.]*\)/\1 \1/') gff3.txt` works ) then `join`ing them and writing a simple `sed` matching script should work very, very fast, cause it would parse only one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution and I kinda like it but be sure to copy your file first as it will replace content on it and you may lose informations if that does not work as expected.

GNU sed :

```
sed 's, +,$ ,g' position.txt | xargs -I {} sed -i 's {} g' gff3.txt
```

MAC OS :

```
sed -E 's, +,$ ,' position.txt | xargs -I {} sed -i '' 's {} g' gff3.txt
```

`xargs -I` will execute sed for each line of position.txt on gff3.txt

`{}` will be replaced by the line of gff3.txt. First column is used as pattern, second as the new value.

Comment: and how this would make a proper replacements?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Have you tried this solution ? I got the exact expected result.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest have you tried the GNU sed solution ? Looks like your sed does not like the '' after -i option

Comment: I think that I fixed the GNU solution. Problem is that position.txt has multiple spaces and GNU sed don't like this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: make a proper corrections for MacOS solution if it pretends to be an alternative

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it works on my MacOS so I don't understand well what is the problem here. I don't know well the differences between all versions of bash/sed, if you have any suggestion please let me know.

Comment: @CorentinLimier Strangely it paste weird pattern like this: `scaffold1000|size145372:94701-95924987-23149`. Before it was `scaffold1000|size145372.2` in the `gff3.txt`, and in the `position.txt` near by  `scaffold1000|size145372.2` there is this pattern: `scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149`, and few line below, near by `scaffold1000|size145372.16` there is `scaffold1000|size145372:94701-95924`. So it concatenate the XXXX:XXXX pattern for all scaffold which have the same first number after the dot like scaffoldXX|sizeXX.1, scaffoldXX|sizeXX.12, scaffoldXX|sizeXX.13... (I use the MacOs code)

Comment: Could you try this ? `sed -E 's, +,$ ,' position.txt | xargs -I {} sed -i '' 's {} g' gff3.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
sed "$(<position.txt sed 's/\./\\./g' | xargs -n2 printf "s@%s@%s@g\n")" gff3.txt
```

First I take `position.txt` substitute every `.` with `\.`, so that it's escaped for `sed`. Then from each line I generate `sed` substitution command `s/<first column>/<second column>/g` using `xargs` and simple `printf`. The output is fed to `sed` as the script and `sed` takes `gff3.txt` and runs the transformations on it. If there are no "strange" inputs (embedded spaces, newlines, all strings are unique, etc.), I think this may handle.

Test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF >gff3.txt 
scaffold1000|size145372 . gene 16987 23149 . - . ID=evm.TU.scaffold1000|size145372.2;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold1000|size145372.2
scaffold1000|size145372 . mRNA 16987 23149 . - . ID=evm.model.scaffold1000|size145372.2;Parent=evm.TU.scaffold1000|size145372.2;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold1000|size145372.2
scaffold1000|size145372 . exon 22965 23149 . - . ID=evm.model.scaffold1000|size145372.2.exon1;Parent=evm.model.scaffold1000|size145372.2
scaffold9|size467357 . gene 373475 396789 . + . ID=evm.TU.scaffold9|size467357.56;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold9|size467357.56
scaffold9|size467357 . mRNA 373475 396789 . + . ID=evm.model.scaffold9|size467357.56;Parent=evm.TU.scaffold9|size467357.56;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold9|size467357.56
scaffold9|size467357 . exon 373475 373695 . + . ID=evm.model.scaffold9|size467357.56.exon1;Parent=evm.model.scaffold9|size467357.56
EOF

cat <<EOF >position.txt
scaffold1000|size145372.2  scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149
scaffold9|size467357.56    scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789
EOF

cat <<EOF >exp.txt
scaffold1000|size145372 . gene 16987 23149 . - . ID=evm.TU.scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149
scaffold1000|size145372 . mRNA 16987 23149 . - . ID=evm.model.scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149;Parent=evm.TU.scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149
scaffold1000|size145372 . exon 22965 23149 . - . ID=evm.model.scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149.exon1;Parent=evm.model.scaffold1000|size145372:16987-23149
scaffold9|size467357 . gene 373475 396789 . + . ID=evm.TU.scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789
scaffold9|size467357 . mRNA 373475 396789 . + . ID=evm.model.scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789;Parent=evm.TU.scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789;Name=EVM%20prediction%20scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789
scaffold9|size467357 . exon 373475 373695 . + . ID=evm.model.scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789.exon1;Parent=evm.model.scaffold10008|size45161:373475-396789
EOF

sed "$(<position.txt sed 's/\./\\./g' | xargs -n2 printf "s@%s@%s@g\n")" gff3.txt > output.txt

diff exp.txt output.txt
```

`diff` prints nothing, so It works for specified example input and expected output.

Comment: "billions of lines" factor will be a crucial testing criteria for viability of this approach